# Getting the mirroring state of a camera using Media Foundation under Windows 7

Tags: windows, directshow, ms-media-foundation

With IMF on Win7, how can I find out whether the camera driver mirrors the preview image? In Win8, there is the IMFCaptureSource interface which exposes the GetMirrorState method. I couldn't find a similar method in Win7.

Comment: It might so happen you don't have it in Windows 7. In DirectShow it's `IAMVideoControl::GetMode` however I don't think it's widely used and supported.

Comment: Have you got an example for doing it using IAMVideoControl::GetMode?

Comment: Example would be straightforward, per MSDN. The problem would be finding a device that supports this well: both in hardware and on driver so that that this interface and method is available, miplemented and works well.